# Traefik, how to append parameters to path?

Tags: traefik

I am using [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) as an API gateway in front of an (internal) [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)-provider.

Using my OAuth2-provider directly works fine:

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' -d 'username=username&password=password' \
  'http://my-oauth-provider/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret
// 200 OK, getting a Bearer-token
```

In my usecase, I want to hide the [Oauth2 client_id](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.2) in the Traefik-configuration. An API-consumer would only provide username/password, client_id etc. will be added to the HTTP request by Traefik.

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' -d 'username=username&password=password' \
  'http://my-traefik-api-gateway/oauth/token
```

(How) can this be done using Traefik?

**What I tried so far**

I hoped to solve my challenge using [Traefik's ReplacePathRegex-modifiers](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#modifiers) like so:

```
[frontends]
  [frontends.oauth-provider]
  backend = "my-oauth-provider"
    [frontends.oauth-provider.routes.route1]
    rule = "ReplacePathRegex: ^(.*)$ $1?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret; Path: /oauth/token"
```

This does not work out. From the Traefik logs I assume, the appended parameters are not added to the actual query-parameters going to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

`path` is different from `query parameters`.

There is no way to do what you want.

You can only change the path with the modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your response¹!

¹ Not marking as solution, as my (unsolvable) problem is still open.

Comment: @Idez Ah this is unfortunate. I was hoping to use traefik as a drop-in replacement for an apache proxy. A few of the existing apache `RewriteRules` deals with replacing numbers in the path into query parameters, for example `/path/123` becomes `/newpath?foo=123`.

Comment: Do you know anything about any updates? I want to proxy requests and serve content form Azure Blob. Appending a SAS could do the trick. Generating auth header is too complex for Traefik header middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to apply this change to traefik then it could work:

```
diff --git middlewares/replace_path_regex.go middlewares/replace_path_regex.go
index d753e86c..da21a259 100644
--- middlewares/replace_path_regex.go
+++ middlewares/replace_path_regex.go
@@ -33,7 +33,13 @@ func (s *ReplacePathRegex) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if s.Regexp != nil && len(s.Replacement) > 0 && s.Regexp.MatchString(r.URL.Path) {
                r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), ReplacePathKey, r.URL.Path))
                r.Header.Add(ReplacedPathHeader, r.URL.Path)
-               r.URL.Path = s.Regexp.ReplaceAllString(r.URL.Path, s.Replacement)
+               replacement := s.Regexp.ReplaceAllString(r.URL.Path, s.Replacement)
+               u, err := r.URL.Parse(replacement)
+               if err != nil {
+                       log.Errorf("bad replacement %s: %s", replacement, err)
+               } else {
+                       r.URL = u 
+               }   
                r.RequestURI = r.URL.RequestURI()
        }   
        s.Handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
```